# Data structure functioning like Database in C or C++

Tags: data-structures

Is there a data structure which gives you functions of a database (like insert, update, delete etc)? For example:

- create a struct like the database table
- store data on it and query on it
- selectively delete it

I know that with a hashtable you can do this (ex: uthash library). But as far as I know updating one column element only is not easy in a hash table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use C structs to represent rows of data and then trees (or maybe hashes) for indexes. There are a lot of little problems you will need to solve, specially in order to make all the operations efficient, but this forms the basis for an in-memory table.

For simple things, a tree structure may be enough.

Comment: Thanks a lot. If possible can you give me some examples of the little problems that needs to be solved. Is it only related to efficiency or any other issues?

Comment: Memory handling. Deleting elements, specifically if you use non-unique indexes. In some scenarios you may prefer to mark entries as invalid instead of removing them from the trees.

Answer (score 2):

Look at [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/). Rather than a relational database system, it is essentially a connectionless, file-based database library that supports SQL. You link your program against it and it provides functions to perform SQL queries over data files.

Comment: If you want an in-RAM database you can use `:memory:` as the filename.

Comment: Thank you both. sqlite seems good. But what I am really looking for is a data structure which does this. Just to know if the main features of a database(ie querying, storing and updating) can be achieved with a data structure. Hope I am clear.

Answer (score 1):

Look At NoSQL itis The RMDBS used By FaceBook