# Database like C++ Data Structure

Tags: c++

I looked over questions like this one, but it seems most answers suggest that one use something like sqlite with an in memory database. Perhaps that is the only real solution but I'll ask regardless.

I have a number of records that look like this :

```
struct record
{
    int id;
    int type;
    // bunch of other data
}
```

The problem involves storing a number of these in a data structure that would allow for efficient runtime queries like

```
GetAllForId(int)
GetAllOfType(int)
GetAllOfTypeAndId(int,int)
```

There can be multiple records of 'type' for a given 'id'
There can be multiple records of 'type' for different 'id'

I also want to be able to easily modify the values in the results of any

```
GetAllOfTypeAndId(int,int)
```

And ofcourse make insertions and deletions with a (preferably) low cost. Although insertions are infrequent so I can eat a bit of cost here.

For reference, I have tried the following solutions :

```
multimap<type,record>
```

Then just iterate on all records to find the one of the relevant type. Feels really cumbersome especially when doing GetAllOfTypeAndId queries, is good for GetAllOfId Queries

```
map<id,map<type,record>>
```

Allows for good GetAllOfTypeAndId queries but fails at providing decent access to GetAllofType

Unfortunately because of the nature of this project, I may not be able to use a relational database system, even if its in memory.

Comment: I did look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6522788/data-structure-functioning-like-database-in-c-or-c)

My question is similar but not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a class and container and its iterators.

```
class DB
{
  private:
    typedef list<Record>::iterator iterator;

    list<Record> records;
    iterator     itForId; 

  public:
    // return iterator of first record with id == parameter
    iterator GetFirstForId(int id); 
    iterator GetNextForId(int id);

    iterator end()   {return records.end();}

};
```

Deleting records can mess with the iterators so it might be better to mark records for deletion and later batch delete when not iterating through a container.

```
class DataRecord : public  Record
{
  bool markedForDeletion;
};
```

Comment: Although a cool solution, this is unlikely to have good big O performance (since each search would be `O(n)`), and would require a manual data structure to perform such indexing. MultiIndex is great, because it does all this for you out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want a [MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html). Joaquin M Lopez has provided an excellent data structure which allows indexes across multiple fields, member functions, or other properties of a struct/class.

In your case, we could do something like:

```
struct record
{
    int id;
    int type;
    // bunch of other data
};

struct id_tag {};
struct type_tag {};

using record_container = boost::multi_index_container<
    record,
    boost::indexed_by<
        boost::hashed_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<id_tag>,
            boost::multi_index::member<record, int, &record:id>
        >,
        boost::hashed_non_unique<
            boost::multi_index::tag<type_tag>,
            boost::multi_index::member<record, int, &record:type>
        >
    > 
>;
```

We can now access the data from a unique, hashed index of the ID (a regular hashmap, like `unordered_map`), or a non-unique, hashed index of the type (like `unordered_multimap`) using views of the data.

```
record_container data;
// .... Fill with data

// Find by ID
auto& id_view = data.get<id_tag>();
auto id_it = id_view.find(15);
if (id_it == id_view.end()) {
    // not found
} else {
    // found
}
```

You may also create composite keys and do complex logic fairly easy with such a container:

```
using composite = boost::multi_index::composite_key<
    record,
    boost::multi_index::member<record, int, &record::id>,
    boost::multi_index::member<record, int, &record::type>
>;
```

**Edit**

If you cannot use Boost, I have a fork of [MultiIndex](https://github.com/Alexhuszagh/multi_index) which uses C++11 features and does not require Boost. It solely depends on a small subset of [Brigand](https://github.com/Alexhuszagh/brigand/), a C++11, template metaprogramming, header-only library.

Comment: Ah , yeah , saw the boost option as well, sadly boost is a strict no go :( (not my rules)

Sorry, your answer is def what I would do if I could convince the team to use boost, not my cal doe :'(

Comment: @Vidrohi You're lucky, I wasn't going to recommend it, but I actually have a Boost-less fork of MultiIndex. Boost was a no-go for me too.

Comment: @Vidrohi Added it to the link, if that works for you. I've found MultiIndex to be handy enough, even if we weren't allowed to use Boost.